# Limit Dask CPU and Memory Usage (Single Node)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I am running Dask on a single computer where running `.compute()` to perform the computations on a huge parquet file will cause dask to use up all the CPU cores on the system.

```
import dask as dd

df = dd.read_parquet(parquet_file)  # very large file
print(df.names.unique().compute())
```

Is it possible to configure dask to use a specific number of CPU cores and limit its memory usage to say 32 GB? Using Python 3.7.2 and Dask 2.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask.distributed.Client creates a LocalCluster for which you can explicitly set the memory use and the number of cores.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask import dataframe as dd

def names_unique(x):
    return x['Names'].unique()

client = Client(memory_limit='2GB', processes=False,
                n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=2)

# Data generation
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], size=1000000),
                   'sales': np.arange(1000000)})
df.to_parquet('parq_df')
ddf = dd.read_parquet('parq_df', npartitions=10)

# Custom computation
sent = client.submit(names_unique, ddf)
names_unique = sent.result().compute()
client.close()
```

Output:

```
names_unique
Out[89]: 
0    D
1    B
2    C
3    A
Name: Names, dtype: object
```

Comment: How different is your approach from defining the resource limits using `cluster = LocalCluster(memory_limit=...)` and then passing it into  `client = Client(cluster)`

Comment: As far as I know they are equivalent - a LocalCluster is created automatically when a Client is instantiated.